# Trying to echo variable value into the input type name

Tags: php, html, forms

I want to create dynamic names based on a variable value. I use a variable `$count` which holds 0 initially and is incremented giving each input type a different value.

Sadly after I submit the form and I try to acess those variables they don't exist.
The variables should be $0,$1,$2 etc depending on the number of the input types.
Before acessing them I have extracted the POST array.

```
while ($nrpyetjeve >0)
{
  $raport="SELECT * FROM $emrikategorise WHERE Id=$nrpyetjarandom";
  $result1=mysql_query($raport);
  $rrjeshti=mysql_fetch_assoc($result1);
  echo "<h3>- {$rrjeshti['Pyetja']}</h3><br/><br/>";
  echo "<ul><li>{$rrjeshti['Pgj1']}</li>";
  echo "<li>{$rrjeshti['Pgj2']}</li>";
  echo "<li>{$rrjeshti['Pgj3']}</li>";
  echo "<li>{$rrjeshti['Pgj4']}</li></ul>";
  echo "<br/><br/>";
```

**This is the problem**

```
  echo "<input type=\"text\" size=\"15\" name='$count'/>";
  echo "<br/><br/>";
  array_push($zgjidhjet,$rrjeshti['Pgjsakt']);
  $nrpyetjeve=$nrpyetjeve-1;
  $nrpyetjarandom=rand(1,$nrrjeshta);
  $count=$count+1;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `$_POST['0']`?

Comment: What made you think you could use numbers as variables in PHP?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I extracted Post and tried to acess the variables, it does not work.

Comment: @AbraCadaver hmmmmm. I am actually trying to use them as variable names, not variables. They are on a form and when the form is submitted the variable names gets the value.

Comment: If you extract them they are invalid because PHP vars cannot start with a number.

Comment: @AbraCadaver Thanks this is what I needed. Edit your answer and you will get the correct answer. I totally forgot about that one. I will use the array idea of yours. Just edit your answer to contain the line above also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `register_globals` or try and `extract()` these variables, they are invalid, as PHP variables cannot start with a number (or be a number).  You need to access the `$_POST` superglobal.  A better approach would be to use an array:

```
echo "<input type=\"text\" size=\"15\" name='text[$count]'/>";
```

Then access as `$_POST['text'][0]` etc.  Now all of your text inputs are grouped under the `$_POST['text']` and you can group checkboxes etc. as well.  You could then `extract()` these (not recommended).

Answer (score 2):

"Register globals" will only work if the array keys of `$_POST` et al. are valid variable names.

For example, if you have `<input name="foo-bar" />`, you can't expect `$foo-bar` to come out as a variable. Instead, use `$_POST['foo-bar']`.

In your case, it would be `$_POST['0']`, `$_POST['1']` and so on.

In general, relying on "Register globals" is a *bad* idea.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't say that its a bad idea. If we were in 1999 and that's the first PHP code written by a fresh developer. ;-)

Comment: I should have mentioned before that I do extract the post array before.

Comment: `extract` works in the same was as Register globals. In both cases, it relies on the array key being a valid variable name.

Comment: But you are right on using $_POST as a php variable cannot start with a number.

Comment: Both your answers are correct, since I cannot award you both with the right answer , I gave you twice a +1 . Thanks for the help, the problem is fixed.